# Error after creating a record in apex class

Tags: apex, class, error, create-records

I get this error after clicking a button:

> The name can only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters. It must begin with a letter and be unique, and must not include spaces, end with an underscore, or contain two consecutive underscores.

I need to create new record for my custom object. Here is my code:

```
public class addVehicle {

public String caryear {get;set;}
public String carmake {get;set;}
public String carmodel {get;set;}
public addVehicle () {
    caryear='';
    carmake='';
    carmodel='';
}

public String getResponse() {
    Vehicle__c vehicleObject = new Vehicle__c (Year__c = caryear, Make__c = carmake, Model__c = carmodel);

    try {
      insert vehicleObject; // inserts the new record into the database
    } catch (DMLException e) {
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error creating new vehicle.'));
      return null;
    }

    return '{"success":"true"}';

}
}
```

I get values from custom selects with JS. Help please :)

Kind regards,
Nick

Comment: Do you have a workflow rule setting the name to the concatenation of the make model and year? If so then it would be setting the name to "" based on the code you posted

Comment: this looks like a problem with the page/JS code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to delete apex class and use Visualforce page only. I did like this:

```
<apex:form >

<apex:inputHidden value="{!Vehicle__c.Name}" id="carname"/>
<apex:inputHidden value="{!Vehicle__c.Year}" id="caryear"/>
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="send" id="save" />

</apex:form>

<script>
$('#findBtn').click(function() {

$('.apexp .bPageBlock.apexDefaultPageBlock .pbBody input:nth-child(1)').val(thisName);
$('.apexp .bPageBlock.apexDefaultPageBlock .pbBody input:nth-child(2)').val(thisYear);
$('.form-group-sm input[type=submit]').trigger('click');

});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to provide some name. Change your below line as,

```
Vehicle__c vehicleObject = new Vehicle__c (Name = 'Some String', Year__c = caryear, Make__c = carmake, Model__c = carmodel);
```

Comment: Yes but I don't want to edit code every time I create a record. It needs to generate automatically. For example "a2Rc00000013Hnj". It do this way for now but display error.

P.S. even if I write "Name = 'Some String'" I get this error, although I didn't have record with this name.

Comment: You can either provide default value to it.

Comment: When I set Autonumber to Name it doesn't help... I try VH{0000000} format

Comment: You have to type cast the number to text(String), like String.valueOf(num).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what should I do. Can you provide more info?

Comment: Can you please post the modified version of  "Vehicle__c vehicleObject = new Vehicle__c (Year__c = caryear, Make__c = carmake, Model__c = carmodel)". With Name field to which you are providing autonumber.

Comment: I wrote: Vehicle__c vehicleObject = new Vehicle__c (Name = 'qwerty', Year__c = caryear, Make__c = carmake, Model__c = carmodel) and also i tried without Name.

 Here is my custom object Vehicle: https://imgur.com/a/n62pZ

I provided auto number to Name which you can see at screenshot. For now I changed it to text(80).

Comment: Vehicle__c vehicleObject = new Vehicle__c (Name = 'qwerty', Year__c = caryear, Make__c = carmake, Model__c = carmodel) this is working for you or not

Comment: no, i get error :( I think the problem in something else

Comment: even if i write (Name = 'sss', Year__c = 'caryear', Make__c = 'carmake', Model__c = 'carmodel') i get this error